# One line if statement not working

Tags: ruby

```
<%if @item.rigged %>Yes<%else%>No<%end%>
```

I was thinking of something like this?

```
if @item.rigged ? "Yes" : "No"
```

But it doesn't work. Ruby has the `||=` but I"m not even sure how to use that thing.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Remove `if` from `if @item.rigged ? "Yes" : "No"`

Ternary operator has form `condition ? if_true : if_false`

Comment: If you condition ends in a '?' is it possible to drop it? Ie if the condition is @customer.sales.present? can you drop the '?'? ... don't worry. Found some code I had and tested it. The answer is 'no'

Comment: @JayKilleen You're correct. Ruby is all about clever tricks, but it's _that_ clever (:

Comment: @NikitaRybak  
`s/that/not that`  
:)

Answer (score 204):

In Ruby, the condition and the `then` part of an `if` expression must be separated by either an expression separator (i.e. `;` or a newline) or the `then` keyword.

So, all of these would work:

```
if @item.rigged then 'Yes' else 'No' end

if @item.rigged; 'Yes' else 'No' end

if @item.rigged
  'Yes' else 'No' end
```

There is also a conditional operator in Ruby, but that is completely unnecessary. The conditional operator is needed in C, because it is an operator: in C, `if` is a statement and thus cannot return a value, so if you want to return a value, you need to use something which *can* return a value. And the only things in C that can return a value are functions and operators, and since it is impossible to make `if` a function in C, you need an operator.

In Ruby, however, `if` is an expression. In fact, *everything* is an expression in Ruby, so it *already* can return a value. There is no need for the conditional operator to even *exist*, let alone use it.

BTW: it is customary to name methods which are used to ask a question with a question mark at the end, like this:

```
@item.rigged?
```

This shows another problem with using the conditional operator in Ruby:

```
@item.rigged? ? 'Yes' : 'No'
```

It's simply hard to read with the multiple question marks that close to each other.

Answer (score 93):

One line if:

```
<statement> if <condition>
```

Your case:

```
"Yes" if @item.rigged

"No" if !@item.rigged # or: "No" unless @item.rigged
```

Comment: Or `"No" unless @item.rigged` to prevent the `!`

Comment: This solution is different in that it returns `nil` instead of `'Yes'` if `item.rigged` is true. Single-line if or unless statements return `nil` if the condition isn't met.

Answer (score 36):

From what I know

3 one-liners

1. `a = 10 if <condition>`

example:

```
a = 10 if true # a = 10
b = 10 if false # b = nil
```

2. `a = 10 unless <condition>`

example:

```
a = 10 unless false # a = 10
b = 10 unless true # b = nil
```

3. `a = <condition> ? <a> : <b>`

example:

```
a = true ? 10 : 100 # a = 10
a = false ? 10 : 100 # a = 100
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Dog This is the best answer – I love how succinctly it contrasts all three ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Both the shell and C one-line constructs work (ruby 1.9.3p429):

```
# Shell format
irb(main):022:0> true && "Yes" || "No"
=> "Yes"
irb(main):023:0> false && "Yes" || "No"
=> "No"

# C format
irb(main):024:0> true ? "Yes" : "No"
=> "Yes"
irb(main):025:0> false ? "Yes" : "No"
=> "No"
```

Comment: only the second example is idiomatic ruby

Answer (score 7):

if else condition can be covered with ternary operator

```
@item.rigged? ? 'Yes' : 'No'
```

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, If you need to default to some value if nil you can use:

```
@something.nil? = "No" || "Yes"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget it can generate the content from the ruby tag:

```
  v
<%= @item.rigged? ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

The tick (v) indicates using the equal sign to generate text in the html.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use:**

(@*item.rigged) ? "Yes" : "No"*

If @item.rigged is true, it will return 'Yes' else it will return 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

```
if apple_stock > 1
  :eat_apple
else
  :buy_apple
end
```

Above statement can written in form of ternerary statement in ruby as:

```
apple_stock > 1 ? :eat_apple : :buy_apple
```